# Can't click a button [Python + Selenium]

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, python, xpath

I'm writing a program to automate some actions on a website using Python and Selenium and I need to click a button with this code:

```
<button class="button login" data-popup="login">Change User</button>
```

Using this

```
log_but2 = "//button[@class='button login']"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(log_but2).click()
```

I've tried many combinations of Xpath but neither of them can locate the button, in addition I don't get any error, simply the program continue like it has clicked on it and get another error.
Someone can help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use the compound class in xpath.

Try below code

```
log_but2 = "//button[@data-popup='login']"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(log_but2).click()
```

Comment: You can use it by contains() function. For example xpath in this case could look like this: "//button[contains(@class, 'button login')]". But this is risky because this expression will find all buttons that contains in class attribute 'button login'. The same situation is with @QAMember hint. Solution for that could be to make xpath that will look for attribute and text in button, for example:
"//button[@data-popup='login' and text()='Change User']" or with contains(): "//button[contains(@class, 'button login') and text()='Change User']"

Comment: @wmarchewka, your suggested solution also work fine.But attribute "data-popup" was given by developers for their back end purpose.So I don't think they will give duplicates in same page with same values.

Comment: trust me,  if this is big Web application,  sooner or later there will appear duplicates.  I know this from my experience. If You create XPaths that should stay for a long time it's better to make them unique from the begging ;)